# Stopping/deleting timer created at runtime from a different sub

Tags: vb.net, timer, runtime

If a timer is created in a sub at run time, and a different sub handles it's tick, how would you then stop that timer from ticking, or better yet, delete it? Because the sub that handles the tick keeps on being started.
My project will be creating hundreds, if not thousands of individual timers every run, so this is quite fundamental.

the code example is this:

```
Private Sub createTimer()
Dim testTimer As New Windows.Forms.Timer
AddHandler testTimer.Tick, AddressOf newSub
testTimer.Interval = 5000
testTimer.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub newSub()

'do work

'repeatedly, because the timer keeps ticking
'and I have no idea how to stop it

End Sub
```

How do I stop the timer created in the first sub from the second sub?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to declare the timer outside of your CreateTimer sub then you could stop it from elsewhere;  ie:

```
    Private myTimer As Windows.Forms.Timer

Public Sub InitialiseTimer

    myTimer = New Timer With{.Interval = 5000}
    myTimer.Start

 End Sub
Public Sub stopTimer
    myTimer.Stop
 End Sub
```

Now you could call initialiseTimer and stop timer when you wanted to from wherever you wanted to.